# In c, How does return values work in a function where return values are already added in if statements?

Tags: c, if-statement, return, function-definition

Quick question:

```
int x;
int y;
int function (int a, int b)
{
   if (x == y)
   {if (y == 1) {return -1;}
    else {return 1;}}
   else {return 1;}
}
```

why does the code above ask me to add a return value outside of if-else statement
and what should I be returning?

Comment: The code is fine, except `x` and `y` aren't declared (not in the local scope at least). What was the warning, and which compiler and compiler settings?

Comment: gcc, "control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]"

Comment: can't replicate: https://godbolt.org/z/ebqq9ndGG

Comment: Are you perhaps running some very old version of GCC?

Comment: Your code is missing a semicolon in `else {return 1}` and is missing a close brace `}` too, probably after the `{return 1}` mentioned.

Comment: For the code in the question as you have edited it now, common compilers do not produce the warning you report. Test the code in the question with your compiler and update the question with code that reproduces the problem or, if it does not reproduce, delete the question.

Comment: Im mainly confused about if i have a `return 0;` in either an if statement or an else statement. and a `return 0;` at the end of the function. Which return value will i be receiving?

Comment: @jorghiee: Code flows through an `if` statement, branching to its “then” clause or its “else” clause according to the test condition (or, if there is no “else” clause, then out of the `if` statement). If control reaches a `return` statement, the function returns. Later `return` statements are then irrelevant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so the function still requires me to put a return value at the end even though  i have a return value in an if and an else statement. Meaning it will be never reaching the return value in the function since the if and else both have a return.

Comment: @jorghiee: No, the function does not require you to put a `return` statement at the end. And the compiler does not require that. And the C standard does not require that. If the compiler warned you that control could reach the end of the function, then control could reach the end of the function. You had some mistake in the code. You have not shown code in this question that would produce that error message. Edit the question to show code that actually produces the error message or delete the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe it's a general compiler warning and `return` cases, internally to conditional cases, are not taken into account.

So, this is what the compiler is "seeing":

```
int function (int a, int b)
{
  if condition
  {...}
  else {...}
}
```

... and the compiler is asking "Where is the return?".

You can simply add `return 0; // not needed, only here for avoiding compiler warnings` at the end of your function code and it should be fine.

Comment: so if my else contains a `return 0`  and i also have a `return 0` at the end of the function. which return will i be receiving  ?

Comment: From the moment you hit a `return`, that's the one you will be getting. In fact, if you put `return 12345` at the end of your function, then this will never be reached because the `return` cases in your if-loop will be hit first. It's just a way to satisfy your compiler, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

If you will format the function

```
int x;
int y;

int function (int a, int b)
{
    if (x == y)
    {
        if (y == 1) {return -1;}
        else {return 1}
    else {return 1;}
}
```

you will see that one closing brace is absent.

You have at least to write

```
int function (int a, int b)
{
    if (x == y)
    {
        if (y == 1) {return -1;}
        else {return 1}
    }
    else {return 1;}
}
```

In this case the returned value depends on which condition will evaluate to true.

If the variables `x` and `y` were not yet changed (initially they are implicitly zero-initialized because declared in the file scope) then the inner else statement of this if statement

```
    if (x == y)
    {
        if (y == 1) {return -1;}
        else {return 1}
    }
```

will get the control and the function will return `1` when it will be called.

Pay attention to that the function parameters are not used.

Comment: Im mainly confused about if i have a `return 0;` in either an if statement or an else statement. and a `return 0;` at the end of the function. Which return value will i be receiving?

Comment: @jorghiee The return value depends on the conditions that evaluate to true.